# Display perfectly vertically centered inline elements

Tags: css

I need to display inline three divs with file name, progress bar and a button. The button is always off — lower than the others. How to put them vertically aligned?

Here's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chagrin/n4gfyq2v/.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar" style="width: 600px;">
    <div class="ajax-file-upload-filename">
        1). Untitled-1Very long name file.png
    </div>        
    <div class="ajax-file-upload-progress" style="">
        <div class="ajax-file-upload-bar ajax-file-upload-1432059821500" style="width: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ajax-file-upload-cancel" style="">
        Cancel
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ajax-file-upload-statusbar {
    border: 2px solid #eee;
    margin:auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    display:block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.ajax-file-upload-statusbar:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.ajax-file-upload-filename {
    font-family:'open_sanslight', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.ajax-file-upload-progress {
    margin: 2px 5px 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.3);
}
.ajax-file-upload-bar {
    background: grey;
    width: 0;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.ajax-file-upload-percent {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 3px;
    left: 48%;
}
.ajax-file-upload-cancel {
    background-color: #2d2f30;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'open_sanslight', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: There's nothing that those three divs should be the same height, so they're  fitting to their (different) content. Try setting it so that height (including padding) are consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to `display: inline-block` add `vertical-align: middle`

```css
.ajax-file-upload-statusbar {
border: 2px solid #eee;
margin:auto;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 0 5px;
background:#f2f2f2;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 display:block;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
.ajax-file-upload-statusbar > div{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.ajax-file-upload-statusbar:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.ajax-file-upload-filename {
font-family: 'open_sanslight', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
color: #333;
display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;   
width:200px;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.ajax-file-upload-progress {
margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
display:inline-block;
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(196,196,196,0.3);
     vertical-align: middle;
}
.ajax-file-upload-bar {
background: grey;
width: 0;
height: 16px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
 
.ajax-file-upload-percent {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
top: 3px;
left: 48%;
}
.ajax-file-upload-red {
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 39px 0 -24px #e67a73;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 39px 0 -24px #e67a73;
box-shadow: inset 0 39px 0 -24px #e67a73;
background-color: #e4685d;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'open_sanslight', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 2px 10px;
line-height:16px;
margin-bottom:2px;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #b23e35;
cursor: pointer;
}
.ajax-file-upload-green {
background-color: #2d2f30;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'open_sanslight', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
margin-bottom:2px;
padding: 2px 5px;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}


.ajax-file-upload {
 font-family: 'open_sanslight', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: table;
 height: 20px;
 padding: 5px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-decoration: none;
 /*gradient*/
 background: #4c4c4c; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4d4d4d, #2f2f2f); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(top,  #4d4d4d, #2f2f2f)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4d4d4d, #2f2f2f); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #4d4d4d, #2f2f2f); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #4d4d4d, #2f2f2f); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #4d4d4d, #2f2f2f); /* W3C */
}

.ajax-file-upload:hover,
.ajax-file-upload-green:hover {
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #5c5c5c, #4d4d4d); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(top,  #5c5c5c, #4d4d4d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #5c5c5c, #4d4d4d); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #5c5c5c, #4d4d4d)); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #5c5c5c, #4d4d4d); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #5c5c5c, #4d4d4d); /* W3C */
}

.ajax-upload-dragdrop {
    border: 2px dashed #CCC;
    color: #DADCE3;
    text-align:center;
 margin:15px auto;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 9px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.ajax-upload-dragdrop span {
 font-family: 'open_sanslight', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

.ajax-upload-dragdrop.state-hover
{ border: 2px dashed #333;
}

.ajax-file-upload-error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar" style="width: 600px;">
    <div class="ajax-file-upload-filename">1). Untitled-1Very long name file.png</div>
    <div class="ajax-file-upload-progress" style=""><div class="ajax-file-upload-bar ajax-file-upload-1432059821500" style="width: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ajax-file-upload-green" style="">Cancel</div>
</div>
```